# Logstash won't start as service

Tags: service, logstash

When i start logstash "service logstash start" nothing happen. Logstash status show that service start without any errors. Service consumes RAM and CPU resources only few seconds then it shows 0 ram and cpu. When i start Logstash from /opt/logstash/bin with --debug flag all works fine.

Comment: Which setup manual did you follow? /opt/logstash/bin seems a weird path for me, I always have it in /usr/share/logstash/bin

Comment: I used manual from habrahabr.ru. All worked but suddenly something gone wrong

Comment: I would try and install it from the original webpage. I know this is less useful, but without any error messages, there's that much you can do. In any case keep in mind that the components should have the same version. I had my share of issues not paying attention to that.

Comment: I edited /etc/init.d/logstash When i removed all arguments like path to logs, logstash starts from "service logstash start".